# Using NodeJS server instead of local IIS server in building an MS Word Add-in in Visual Studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017, office-js, office-js-helpers

In this [Official Word Add-In tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/word/word-add-ins?tabs=visual-studio), they are using `VS2017` where they indicate that they are using `local IIS` server. I want to follow the exact same tutorial but instead use NodeJS server. How can I achieve this?

NOTE: I've successfully created a Node.js web app in Azure following this [Official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs); but here they are not using `VS2017`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a project using the Yeoman generator for Office instead -- which sets you up with a project that uses Node (and as a bonus, that gives you a choice of a TypeScript vs. JavaScript project, with all the appropriate configurations).

See more here:  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/creating-office-add-ins-with-any-editor-introducing-yo-office/